# Compose two pictures into one?

Tags: linux, batch-file

I have two lists of images [a0,a1,a2,....] and [b0,b1,b2,..]

All images within one list have the same properties like size.

I look for a way to combine always two images such that I change the size of picture bx, and move it to a specific position in ax. The created picture is larger than the size of ax. Any way to do this?

Here is how it should look like: http://tinypic.com/r/1o22qe/5

Cheers,
Bios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is ImageMagic (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Comment: Well I have no idea how to overlay images with imagemagick. There is only the way of montage

Comment: composite -geometry 440x220+190 a.png b.png z.png ... Solved the Issue, Thanks xinyun